# HTML can't log in

Tags: javascript, html

My code so far is this and it is linked to `main.js`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="grocceryStore">

  <head>
    <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.2/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/items.js"></script>
    <script src="js/product.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
  </head>
  <style>
  body {
     background-color:#D4E6F1;
}
</style>

  <body>
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/wqfHrmJ.png?1" style= "display: block;
margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;"/>
    <div class="container-fluid" ng-controller="grocceryCtrl">
        <font color='#D68910'>
        <h1 class="header"> Mighty's Groceries </h1>
        <div ng-show="!login">
    <p align="center"><input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" ng-model="Username" color="red" class="form-control" style="width: 500px;" /></p>
        <p align="center"><input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" ng-model="Password" class="form-control" style="width: 500px;" /></p>
              <p align="center">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click = "checkLogin()">Login</button>
          </p>
        </div>
```

`main.js`

```
(function () {
  var secretEmptyKey = '[$empty$]'

    app.controller('grocceryCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.selected = undefined; 
      $scope.storeProductArray = storeProductArray;
      var maxNumProducts = 15;
      var discountAmt = 5;
      $scope.purchasedProductArray = [];
      $scope.totalAmt = 0;  
      $scope.login = false;

      $scope.checkLogin = function() {
        if($scope.username == "admin" && $scope.password == "admin") {
            alert("Login Successful!!");
            $scope.login = true;
        }
        else {
            alert("Invalid User name or Password")
        }
      }
```

I though for some reason. It won't let me log on any solutions.
I have tried changing the password and username. I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

From a quick look I can see that your $scope variables do not match.

```
if($scope.Username == "admin" && $scope.Password == "admin") {
    alert("Login Successful!!");
    $scope.login = true;
}
else {
    alert("Invalid User name or Password")
}
```

Note, I changed $scope.username to $scope.Username as defined in ng-model within HTML and same for the password model.

Edit:

To change a CSS style of the button within your Angular application, you need to defined ng-style tag on the element you want to dynamically apply styling to.

Your button will change to

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-style="btnStyle" ng-click = "checkLogin()">Login</button>
```

And your controller could become

```
if($scope.Username == "admin" && $scope.Password == "admin") {
    alert("Login Successful!!");
    $scope.login = true;
    $scope.btnStyle = { 'background' :'green'};
}
else {
    alert("Invalid User name or Password")
    $scope.btnStyle = { 'background' :'red'};
}
```

Because ng-style takes an object, when you put btnStyle inside the ng-style directive it'll expect an object in the $scope variable. For this reason you must declare the variable in the head of your controller too. It can remain empty as long as it's defined.

Therefore, put this line below at the top of your controller body.

```
$scope.btnStyle = {};
```

Documentation for [ng-style](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle).

Comment: thank you Adriani6. I would not have noticed such small mistake without you pointing out. One more think how do I change the buttons color?.